# How can I convert map into 10 mile square tiles and find out which tile lat/long falls in?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, mercator

This is turning out to be more complicated than I thought... map projections, mercator coordinates, something about EPSG:4326, and so on.

**What I want to do.**

1. Given lat, long find which tile they belong to.
2. Given a tile find its bounds in lat,long.
3. Tile should be ~ 10 miles long.

I can't simply divide lat/long by some number to get 10 mile tiles as distance between longitude changes from equator to poles.

If I let go notion of 10 mile block and just roll with virtual blocks then it's fine.

Tried Looking at how google maps does it, it didn't make sense.

They basically somehow convert lat/long to 0-256, 0-256. Then take calculate some sort of value called pixel value not sure what is that, `coords * 2 ^ zoom level`. Then divide it by 256 to get tile number.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with spheric coordinates you should have a third parameter, the radius.
First you have to do is to mesh your map, plane, square, parametric equation, etc... within the radius you should be able to know the triple integral of your 3D plane.
otherwise take a look at this image: [image: Phi = lat, etc]

I will suggest you to use sageMath, it is a python library for mathematical computation very useful to see your mathematical work.

Conclusion: Get the area of the plane, mesh it with a parameter of units ( 1 cm, 1m, 1km, etc...), see if 10 mile tiles fit in your area.